# Check if a function is available in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I would like to detect if the user has enabled Reduce Transparency. It's simple you just call the func `UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled()` and it returns a `Bool`. But my app targets iOS 7 and 8 and this function isn't available on iOS 7.

In Objective-C, this is how I checked to see if that function exists:

```
if (UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled != NULL) { }
```

In Swift, I can't figure out how to check if it exists or not. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174422/check-if-a-func-exists-in-swift), you can simply use optional chaining and if it's `nil` then it doesn't exist, but that is restricted to Obj-C protocols apparently. Xcode 6.1 doesn't like this:

```
let reduceMotionDetectionIsAvailable = UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled?()
```

It wants you to remove the ?. And of course if you do so it will crash on iOS 7 because that function doesn't exist.

What is the proper way to check if these types of functions exist?

Comment: Parentheses after a function expression invoke the function. What happens if you leave them off?

Comment: If you leave off () it says the same thing - delete the ?: `Operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is '() -> Bool'`. Also if you move the ? after the (), it's all the same error message.

Comment: I suspect it is indeed not available yet. From my understanding, optional chaining is used for class variables. `UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled` is more like static function

Comment: What happens if you assign the function to a variable with an optional closure type? `let reduceMotionDetectionIsAvailable : (() -> Bool)? = UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A proper check for availability has been added in Swift 2. This is recommended over other options mentioned here.

```
var shouldApplyMotionEffects = true
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    shouldApplyMotionEffects = !UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're okay with being a little bit cheeky, you can always open the UIKit binary using the library loader and see if it can resolve the symbol:

```
let uikitbundle = NSBundle(forClass: UIView.self)
let uikit = dlopen(uikitbundle.executablePath!, RTLD_LAZY)
let handle = dlsym(uikit, "UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled")
if handle == nil {
    println("Not available!")
} else {
    println("Available!")
}
```

The `dlopen` and `dlsym` calls can be kinda expensive though so I would recommend keeping the `dlopen` handle open for the life of the application and storing somewhere the result of trying to `dlsym`. If you don't, make sure you `dlclose` it.

As far as I know this is AppStore safe, since `UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled` is a public API.

Comment: cheeky as in get yourself into trouble when Apple's underlying implementation changes without warning. `dlopen()` is getting too far under the hood to be practical for a serious app on the app store to gamble on.

Answer (score 3):

You could check to see if you're running in iOS 8 or higher --

```
var reduceMotionEnabled = false
if NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(NSOperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 8, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)) {
    reduceMotionEnabled = UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled()
}
```

I don't *think* there's another way to tell. So in theory, if you were able to check, trying to access the function name without the `()` would give you `nil` in iOS 7 and the `() -> Bool` function in iOS 8. However, in order for that to happen, `UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled` would need to be defined as `(() -> Bool)?`, which it isn't. Testing it out yields a function instance in both versions of iOS that crashes if called in iOS 7:

```
let reduceMotionDetectionIsAvailable = UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled
// reduceMotionDetectionIsAvailable is now a () -> Bool
reduceMotionDetectionIsAvailable()
// crashes in iOS7, fine in iOS8
```

The only way I can see to do it without testing the version is simply to define your own C function to check in your bridging header file, and call that:

```
// ObjC
static inline BOOL reduceMotionDetectionIsAvailable() {
    return (UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled != NULL);
}

// Swift
var reduceMotionEnabled = false
if reduceMotionDetectionIsAvailable() {
    reduceMotionEnabled = UIAccessibilityIsReduceMotionEnabled()
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's one way to do it. Apple would recommend against that though and has in the past during WWDC sessions. There's many times you need to detect if a function exists, especially when supporting multiple OSes. Is this something that doesn't exist in Swift? That sounds crazy.

Comment: Thanks, goodness that's terrible. :P Time to file an enhancement request! I won't be using Obj-C, this app is pure Swift.

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple Developer docs ([Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 3) > Interoperability > Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns > API Availability](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)):

> Swift code can use the availability of APIs as a condition at
>   run-time. Availability checks can be used in place of a condition in a
>   control flow statement, such as an `if`, `guard`, or `while`
>   statement.
>
> Taking the previous example, you can check availability in an `if`
>   statement to call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` only if the method
>   is available at runtime:
>
> ```swift
> let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
> if #available(iOS 8.0, macOS 10.10, *) {
>     locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
> }
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can check availability in a `guard` statement,
>   which exits out of scope unless the current target satisfies the
>   specified requirements. This approach simplifies the logic of handling
>   different platform capabilities.
>
> ```swift
> let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
> guard #available(iOS 8.0, macOS 10.10, *) else { return }
> locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
> ```
>
> Each platform argument consists of one of platform names listed below,
>   followed by corresponding version number. The last argument is an
>   asterisk (`*`), which is used to handle potential future platforms.
>
> Platform Names:
>
> - `iOS`
> - `iOSApplicationExtension`
> - `macOS`
> - `macOSApplicationExtension`
> - `watchOS`
> - `watchOSApplicationExtension`
> - `tvOS`
> - `tvOSApplicationExtension`